# Plugin Compatibility Issue Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) and Java 9

Tags: eclipse-plugin, compatibility, java-9, eclipse-oxygen

We upgraded one of our Eclipse 3.x plugins to work with Java 9. 
But when we generated the plugin update site content, and used Eclipse Update functionality to install the new version of the plugin, we encountered the following error in Eclipse Oxygen.

> Removing part descriptor with the 'pluginxxx.bla.bla' id and the 'bla bla' description. **Points to the invalid 'bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView**' class.

This error also appears due to some of the bundled plugins of Eclipse Oxygen itself.

After a hard week we had to

- Uninstall our plugin
- Remove the older versions of the plugin from the Eclipse/plugins folder
- Export the plugin as a deployable plugin under the eclipse plugins directory. (Eclipse/plugins/blabla.jar)
- Restart Eclipse and it worked.

Right click the eclipse plugin project and Run as "Eclipse Application" works fine, but installing the plugin from an "Update Site" causes the plugin to fail loading.

We could not find a solution yet, but it certainly effects our delivery of the plugin. The plugin is used by almost 500 CS students on their personal computers, and 200 lab computers. So the update should be installed using regular Eclipse Update functionality, not by copying the jar into the plugins directory.

Was there a better way to fix this, or something quicker we could've tried (in case this happens again)?

**Update (7 days into the problem)**

We have a workaround: 
Export the feature project with the following settings in the Export Wizard

- Destination/ Directory: Folder of your Plugin Update Site project
- Options/ Package as individual JAR archieves (selected)
- Options/ Generate p2 repository (selected)
- Options/ Allow for binary cycles in target platform (selected)
- Options/ **Use class files compiled in the workspace (essentially selected**)

Install (or update) the plugin from the local (or remote) plugin update site, and the CompatibilityView problem is solved.

In order to have the category listing displayed correctly during install/update new software operations, we added a category.xml file (File/New/Other/Plugin-in Development/Category Definition) in the update site project, defined the categories, and added the feature (versioned as "qualifier").

This is certainly not the way it should be, and we just hope it will be solved in the future Eclipse releases.

By the way current Eclipse Photon integration version has the same problem unfortunately.